# Count documents and return subset

Tags: mongodb

Is there a way to use to MongoDB aggregate framework to:

1. Count the number of documents returned from a `$match`
2. Obtain a subset of these documents with another `$match`

all in one query? I was thinking there might be a way to use multiple `$group` stages in the pipeline to count the documents before the additional `$match` then pass the result to the second `$group`. But I haven't found a way to manage that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's possible and you need [$facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/) pipeline stage which allows you to perform multiple sub-aggregations. Given data like this:

```
db.col.save({ a: 1, b: 2 })
db.col.save({ a: 1, b: 2 })
db.col.save({ a: 1, b: 2 })
db.col.save({ a: 1, b: 4 })
db.col.save({ a: 3, b: 2 })
```

You can use below aggregation:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $match: { a: 1 }
    },
    {
        $facet: {
            total : [
                { $count: "count" }
            ],
            subset: [
                { $match: { b: 2 } },
                { $project: { _id: 0 } }
            ]
        }
    }
])
```

which outputs:

```
{ "total" : [ { "count" : 4 } ], "subset" : [ { "a" : 1, "b" : 2 }, { "a" : 1, "b" : 2 }, { "a" : 1, "b" : 2 } ] }
```

Each sub-aggregation will be returned as an array however you can apply next pipeline stages like for instance `$unwind` on `count`.